# Prove that the set $\{1,2,3,...,(3^n-1)/2\}$ can be split into $n$ sum free sets

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that the set $\{1,2,3,...,(3^n-1)/2\}$ can be split into $n$ sum free sets (a sum free set is basically a set in which no element is a sum of any other elements in the set).
I was reading Arthur Engel's Problem Solving Strategies and the solution given  is as follows:

> We want to give a lower bound for Schur function $f(n)$  which is the smallest number so that the integers $1,2,3,..,f(n)$ can be arranged in $n$  sum free . If the table with $n$ rows $x_1,x_2,...,\space\space\space   ...,  u_1,u_2,...$ has sum free rows ,then $n+1$ rows $3x_1,3x_1-1,3x_2,3x_2-1,3x_3,3x_3-1,3x_4,3x_4-1,...,1,4,7,...,3f(n)+1$ give a similar table for the inyeger $3f(n)+1$ . For $n=2$ from the table ${1,4,2,3}$,we get the table
> $3,2,12,11$\
> $6,5,9,8$\
> $1,4,7,10,13$
> In any case we have $f(n+1)\geq 3f(n)+1$ and since $f(1)=1$ ,we have $f(3)\geq 13$ ,$f(4)\geq 40$ .Thus, we get
> $f(n)\geq 1+3+3^2+...+3^{n-1}=(3^n-1)/2$
>
> > I did not get the idea of this solution . Can anyone please explain this solution? I am not getting the idea of this solution .

Answer (score 1):

This is the key claim: Suppose $A \subset \mathbf{N}$ is sum-free. Then we claim that $B = 3A + \{-1,0\}$ is also sum-free. Here this means that $B$ consists of all points of the form $\def\eps{\epsilon}3a + \eps$ where $a \in A$ and $\epsilon \in \{-1,0\}$. The proof is easy. If $(3a_1+\eps_1) + (3a_2 + \eps_2) = (3a_3 + \eps_3)$ then $\eps_1 + \eps_2 \equiv \eps_3 \pmod 3$, which actually implies $\eps_1 + \eps_2 = \eps_3$ since $\eps_1,\eps_2,\eps_3 \in \{-1,0\}$. Hence $a_1 + a_2 = a_3$, which is a contradiction.

Now note that the infinite arithmetic progression $P = \{x \equiv 1 \pmod 3\}$ is also sum-free. Thus if $A_1, \dots, A_n$ are sum-free sets covering $\{1, \dots, N\}$ and $B_i = 3A_i + \{-1,0\}$ for each $i$ then $B_1, \dots, B_n, P$ are sum-free sets covering $\{1, \dots, 3N+1\}$. This proves $f(n+1) \geq 3f(n) + 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can you please explain the fact $P=\{x\equiv 1(mod 3)\}$ is sum-free....I mean how did you conclude this ...does $x\in A$ ? Furthermore can you please explain how did you conclude that $f(n+1)\geq 3f(n)+1$?...and how does that proves that  the set $\{1,2,3,...,(3n−1)/2\} $can be partitioned into $n$ sum free sets...

Comment: The sum of two elements in $P$ is $2$ mod 3, so not in $P$, so $P$ is sum-free. Note in your definition of $f(n)$ you said "smallest" where really you mean "largest". By definition of $f(n)$ there is a way of covering $1,\dots,f(n)$ with $n$, and this shows there is a way of covering $1, \dots,3f(n)+1$ with $n+1$, so $f(n+1) \geq 3 f(n)+1$. Then solving the recurrence gives $f(n) \geq (3^n-1)/2$ (try it for small values of $n$).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Just one thing more....according to the book it meant that the largest "smaller bound" for $f(n)$ i.e $(3^n-1)/2$ and can please say what do you mean by that we can cover $1,2,3,..,f(n)$ with $n$ and how does that show that there is a way of covering $1,2,...3f(n)+1$ with $n+1$ ...I am not quite getting this part...